# What can we do if we accidentally buy tamarind puree instead of paste?

Tags: asian-cuisine, tamarind

My wife was planning to make us pad thai, but accidentally bought tamarind puree instead of tamarind paste.

We would like to still use the puree if possible - is there any way we could use the puree instead?  Is the difference noticeable enough that our recipe can't be made with the puree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between the two is that puree has a little more liquid.

You should add more puree than the recipe calls for paste to compensate for it being more dilute.

In some recipes, the extra liquid could be a problem, however, I don't think it will make any difference in pad thai in the quantities that it is used.

Comment: My wife wound up just extracting the excess liquid from the puree to make it into a paste - it came out great.  Not sure if it'd still be the same with all the liquid in it, but thank you for this answer!